# How to get stream of all users in firebase in flutter?

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm working on a chat app and there is a collection called 'users' stores all users of the app.
When a user start a chat with any one, he stores the user in a collection called 'chats' that have the id of the other user and in the id stores another collection 'messages' to store the messages between them.

I want to get all the users in 'chats' collection and stores them in List of ChatUsers, but when i print the count of the users, i got zero and i dont know why.
I use stream to get all the users because i want the show all chat users in the main screen to show the last messages.

Can any one tell me the wrong with the code below?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up. Also see: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 0):

Since loading `snapshots` is an asynchronous operation, your `emit` now happens before any data is loaded. The call to `emit` needs to be inside the `map` callback:

```
chatsRef.snapshots().map((event){
  for(...){
    ...
  }
  emit(GetAllChatUserSuccessState()); // 
});
```